# Problems with routing, Users and IndexUsers

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-app-kit

So I started playing around with ember. The I switched over to the "Ember App Kit" after around one week. Now I can't seem to get the routing and controllers to work correctly.

I have

```
routes/
--- users.js
--- users/
------- index.js
```

#### Router

```
this.resource('users', function() { 
  this.route('new'); 
  this.route('edit', { path: ':userId' }); //this.route('edit'); 
});
```

But it seems like only my users.js gets called - I was under the impression(from the Ember docs) that going to "#/users" would call: UsersRoute -> UsersIndexRoute, that would render
templates/users.hbs and templates/users/index.hbs ? Same goes for controller; it would first call the UsersController then the UsersIndexController?

Comment: You should post your router's mappings. The file structure doesn't have influence which routes are used.

Comment: Will you please add the UsersRoute, UsersIndexRoute, UsersController, UsersIndexController, users.hbs etc

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs - click here to see](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resources):

***NOTE: If you define a resource using this.resource and do not supply a function, then the implicit resource.index route is not created. In that case, /resource will only use the ResourceRoute, ResourceController, and resource template.***

```
Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('users', function(){}); // this will have index route
});
```

Comment: this.resource('users', function() {
        this.route('new');
        this.route('edit', { path: ':userId' });
        //this.route('edit');
    });

this is what I have atm.